# Python to php Image uploader

Tags: php, python, upload

I'm trying to upload an image from my computer via python script to a php site. 
Everything I tried failed and now I hope you can give me some ideas / solutions.

I tried using the requests library in python to send the image. 
The php script should return a status to the python (maybe in .json Format?)

Thank you for your help!

Code Ideas: 
Py:

```
import requests
url = 'http://url.com/upload.php'
files = {'file': open('image.png', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

PHP:

```
<?php
print_r($_FILES); 
//Copy files to folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
//Return Statement to client
?>
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code.

Comment: Just added some of my code ideas

Comment: Did you have a look in your webservers logfile? That should help you understand what is wrong.